# Same request but over time interval in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say that I have a 'complex' method to create an user's statement for particular day. My goal is to create the statement of each user in single query for a period of time.

For example, if today's statement is :

| User id | statement | at date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OK | 05/06/2021 |
| 2 | NOK | 05/06/2021 |
| 3 | OK | 05/06/2021 |

And yesterday's statement was :

| User id | statement | at date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NOK | 05/05/2021 |
| 2 | OK | 05/05/2021 |
| 3 | OK | 05/05/2021 |

Then if I want to compute [yesterday, today] (time interval) query the result will be :

| User id | statement | at date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OK | 05/06/2021 |
| 2 | NOK | 05/06/2021 |
| 3 | OK | 05/06/2021 |
| 1 | NOK | 05/05/2021 |
| 2 | OK | 05/05/2021 |
| 3 | OK | 05/05/2021 |

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL without using Union, on custom time interval ?

My current solution in simple :

```
SELECT
        *, -- find statement with case when
        CURRENT_DATE as 'at date'
FROM
        t
WHERE
        some_dates <= CURRENT_DATE
AND
        some_date > CURRENT_DATE - X

UNION

SELECT
        *,
        CURRENT_DATE -1 as 'at date'
FROM
        t
WHERE
        some_dates <= CURRENT_DATE - 1
AND
        some_date > CURRENT_DATE - X - 1

UNION

-- Same with current_date - 2
...
-- Same with current_date - N
```

Comment: Isn't that just ordering? ORDER BY "at date", "User id".

Comment: You seem to just want `WHERE` with a filter on the dates.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not have the "at date" column. I need to generate it with the statement for each user. The statement is computed with the CURRENT_DATE and previous DATE. So yesterdayd's statement was calculate with CURRENT_DATE - 1 and previous, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `BETWEEN` operator to filter the interval you want and `ORDER BY atdate DESC` and `atdate ASC`:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE atdate BETWEEN '2021-05-05' AND '2021-05-06'
ORDER BY atdate DESC, userid ASC;

 userid | statement |   atdate   
--------+-----------+------------
      1 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      2 | NOK       | 2021-05-06
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      1 | NOK       | 2021-05-05
      2 | OK        | 2021-05-05
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-05
```

If you're looking for a way to always get the date of today and yesterday you can use `CURRENT_DATE` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE atdate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-1 AND CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY atdate DESC, userid ASC;

 userid | statement |   atdate   
--------+-----------+------------
      1 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      2 | NOK       | 2021-05-06
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      1 | NOK       | 2021-05-05
      2 | OK        | 2021-05-05
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-05
```

Or in case your table has no records with dates greater than the current date (today)

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE atdate >= CURRENT_DATE-1
ORDER BY atdate DESC, userid ASC;

 userid | statement |   atdate   
--------+-----------+------------
      1 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      2 | NOK       | 2021-05-06
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-06
      1 | NOK       | 2021-05-05
      2 | OK        | 2021-05-05
      3 | OK        | 2021-05-05
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dec5a9ed31aeb2e98813c2b382463810)

Comment: The "At date" column is generated with the "statement"... The date 'Statement' is generated with the CURRENT_DATE and previous days data

So for each days, I take previous days data, compute the statement and generate the "At date" for this particular snapshot date

Comment: @Rallyx so the columns `statement` and `atdate` do not physically exist? Is this your problem?

Comment: They do not exist. I'm able to generate them one by one, for each days, adjusting my parameters (dates) in query, Using `WHERE XXX < CURRENT_DATE`  to `WHERE XXX < CURRENT_DATE - N` with N the number of days in my interval.

So with this naive method I need to make N union or N queries...

Comment: @Rallyx could you add the code you use to generate the statments and dates?

Comment: I edited my post. My real query is somehow 280 lines long. This is a simplify version...

Comment: @Rallyx is `X` an arbitrary number you provide in the query or is it a column?

Comment: X is an arbitrary integer, but alway the same for all.